# printing mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a mysql database name `cstudents` with table students and `sid`,`sname`,`sdiv` and `passyr` as the table columns. i intend to print this entire table. here is the code i tried:

```
$con3=mysql_connect(DB_HOST1,DB_USER1,DB_PASSWORD1) or die ("failed to connect to mysql".mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME1,$con3) or die ("failed to connect to mysql".mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT sid, sname, rollno, passyr FROM cstudents.student;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error:'.mysql_error($query));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result,mysql_both)) {
    echo $row['sid'];
    echo $row['sname'];
    echo $row['sdiv'];
    echo $row['passyr'];
}
```

> executing this gives: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''
>   (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have missed closing double quotes in your query, instead of:

```
$query = "SELECT sid, sname, rollno, passyr FROM cstudents.student;
```

must be:

```
$query = "SELECT sid, sname, rollno, passyr FROM cstudents.student";
```

And one suggestion: start using `mysqli_*` functions instead of already depreciated `mysql_*`.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. but now it gives this error:mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Comment: you need to change ALL functions, including `mysql_error`, should be `mysqli_error($con3)`.